# weblogic configuration for zipping data. And filtering content type

Tags: configuration, gzip, weblogic-10.x

I am checking this [link](http://blog.eisele.net/2009/02/using-html-and-http-compression-with.html), which explains for zipping data.
But the problem is,

- cant find the GZIPFilter jar
- and my weburls dont end with any extension. i am using it to zip html page rendered using orbeon.
- and the weblogic 10.x feature **compress-html-template** doesnt work for my orbeon forms. When i tried it my orbeon app was not starting up in weblogic server.

so I searched around and found [PJLfilter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjl-comp-filter/)
and the configuration I figured out should be (guess work with respect to the 1st link)

```
Simply add the PLJFilter-zip.jar into your war's WEB-INF/lib
```

Register the gzip filter in web.xml as:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PJLFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

And add the filter mapping as

```
<filter-mapping>    
    <filter-name>PJLFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>    
</filter-mapping>
```

Also, the above configuration does the filtering for all the content from the server. and i dont want to do that but need to get it more specific for `compressableMimeType="application/x-javascript,text/html,text/css"` (this is corresponding configuration in tomcat)

Please let me know if the configurations are correct. and if i am missing any thing. If there is any work around for zipping, let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `includeContentTypes` configuration of PJL to [only compress files of content types you specify](http://pjl-comp-filter.sourceforge.net/com/planetj/servlet/filter/compression/CompressingFilter.html).

Comment: thanks, your link was the installation doc i was looking for :).